How to add enumeration input argument to json function signature
According to the docs json function signature supports enumeration, however, I can't figure out how to define its type properly.
Example enum:
classdef Word
   enumeration
      Hello,
      World
   end
end

The function sigature would be:
{
    "_schemaVersion": "1.1.0",
    "functionWithEnumInput": {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "inputName",
                "type": "Word",
                "purpose": "How to define the type?"
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "outputName",
                "type": [],
                "purpose": ""
            }
        ],
        "purpose": ""
    }
}

I'm using the function signature to create a CTF file for Matlab Production Server. The CTF is created by the build pipeline and currently it returs: Property "type" has an invalid value: "enumeration:Word".
The function itself is working, I can call it from tests like: functionWithEnumInput(Word.Hello)

I tried "Word" and "enumeration:Word" both result the same error message
According to the docs, the typedef object can't be used with enumerations so I didn't try to use that


In the docs you've linked, it states The JSON file does not support adding descriptions for [...] enumeration values, although your MATLAB functions can have these data types as input or outputs. That sentence suggests that you can't add the description for your enum type input?

The sentence from the docs: If your MATLAB functions have struct or cell data types as inputs or outputs, you can add their descriptions to the JSON file using typedef objects. made me think the description is basically the typedef object. Anyway, I removed the purpose from my example but got the same error message as previously.

Yeah personally I think that sentence can be interpreted two ways, sorry I've not actually is the intended interpretation
